# Why does the constructor of java.util.Date act differently on parameters between int and long?

Tags: java, date

Here's the scenario:

If I pass an `int` to Date as below, the output would be `Thu Jan 22 20:56:36 CST 1970`:

```
System.out.println(new Date(1393430400*1000));
```

When I pass a `long`, the output is just what I intend for: `Thu Feb 27 00:00:00 CST 2014`

```
System.out.println(new Date((long)1393430400*1000));
```

I've checked the method which the `new Date(long l)` invoked. It's just the same one:

```
public Date(long date) {
    fastTime = date;
}
```

Could anyone give me some explanations on this problem? Thanks a lot!

Comment: int overflow most likely

Comment: Also you might want to use `123L` for long `123`, not a cast

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
   System.out.println(new Date(1393430400*1000));
```

in this `1393430400` as `int` will `overflow`. Some different value will get multiply by `1000` and for that you will get the Date.But when you do

```
    System.out.println(new Date((long)1393430400*1000));
```

1393430400 this will be casted to `long` and the multiplication by 1000 will be `long` and `no overflow`.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't realize it.

Answer (score 4):

```
System.out.println(new Date(1393430400*1000));
```

When you do that in crossed the integer range and overflowing happening there. So that is returning standard unix time(`Thu Jan 22 20:56:36 CST 1970`).

That is not the exact value it's getting parsed.

Where as the line

```
System.out.println(new Date((long)1393430400*1000));
```

is clearly indicating/conerting to the long value and the proper parsed date you are getting.

Comment: @Judking it will generate an compile time error. which JDK version you use ?

Answer (score 3):

Try printing the int value on its own:

```
System.out.println(1393430400 * 1000);
```

The output is `1860996096`, which corresponds to the date you are seeing.

This occurs because Java's `int` is a signed 32-bit integer, meaning that the maximum value holdable is 2^31 - 1.  When exceeding that value in calculations, [integer overflow](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_overflow) occurs, leading to values like the one you see above.  For date creation, *always* use longs rather than ints, as longs are 64-bit and can store up to 2^63 - 1.